# MySQL get row position in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is something i have been thinking for hours and still cant get the answer. I want to get the row position.

So, i have this mysql table called 'orders'

```
+-----------------------------+
+ id | bid                    +
+-----------------------------+
+  1 | 4.00                   +
+  2 | 6.00                   +
+  3 | 5.00                   +                 
+  4 | 4.00                   +
+-----------------------------+
```

And i have already managed to get the row position with this function

```
SELECT p.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE bid > p.bid) AS position FROM orders p
```

And the output is

```
+-----------------------------+
+ id | bid      | position    +
+-----------------------------+
+  1 |     4.00 | 3           +
+  2 |     6.00 | 1           +
+  3 |     5.00 | 2           +
+  4 |     4.00 | 3           +
+-----------------------------+
```

Please note that if values are the same they have the same position.

So what i need now is a query where i select a new bid (that does not exist on the table) and tells me in which position this bid will be. It should be something like this: If my new bid is 7.00 in which position will it be? (answer: 1 position), another example: If my new bid is 4.00 in which position will it be? (answer: 3 position)

Im looking for this to be done in SQL. If it is not possible then i will like a php answer.

I hope you guys can help me on this, i have been burning my head the last hours and failed to get this done.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I think you should add a DISTINCT keyword to your subquery. Because if we add `bid=3` to the table it will get `position = 5` with your query. So `4` will be missed.

```
SELECT p.*, 
      (SELECT count(DISTINCT bid)+1 
              FROM orders WHERE bid > p.bid) AS position 
      FROM orders p
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/760089/3)</kbd>

Now we need to know position for new `bid`. Just use your subquery:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT bid)+1 FROM orders WHERE bid > 4
```

Comment: This solution works perfect for me, and you even corrected my first query. Thanks for fast reply and taking your time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Get all distinct bid and append the rank, then join with it.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.position
FROM orders t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT bid, @i:=@i+1 AS position
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT bid 
    FROM orders
    ORDER by bid DESC
  ) a, (SELECT @i:=0) b
) t2 ON t1.bid = t2.bid
```

**[THE SQLFiddle DEMO.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a8f9/13)**

Answer (score 0):

How about simple

```
SELECT count(*)+1 as position FROM orders WHERE bid > :new_bid
```